# confusion in finding $I=\frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c Re\{ z\} \, dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> If C denotes the counterclockwise unit circle, then the value of the contour integral
> $$\frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c Re\{ z\} \, dz \quad \text{is _____ }?$$

Method $1$:
$$Re\{ z\} = \frac{z + \bar{z}}{2} \quad \dots (1)$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c Re\{ z\} \, dz = \frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c \frac{z + \bar{z}}{2} \, dz$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c \frac{z }{2} \, dz + \frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c \frac{\bar{z}}{2} \, dz \quad \dots (2)$$
Now using Cauchy-Integral theorem, we get:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c \frac{z }{2} \, dz=0 \quad \dots (3)$$
as $f(z)=z$ is differentiable at every point inside C ($|z|=1$)
and $\bar{z}=\frac{1}{z}$ for C( $|z|=1$),
so, $eq(2)$ can be rewritten as:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c \frac{z }{2} \, dz + \frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c \frac{\bar{z}}{2} \, dz = 0 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c \frac{1}{z} \, dz$$
$$\frac{1}{2} .1=\frac{1}{2}$$

Method $2$:
Let $z=re^{j \theta}$
$$\implies \frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c Re\{ z\} \, dz = \frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint_c r cos (\theta) \, d(re^{j \theta}) \quad \dots (4)$$
Now, for C : $r=1 $ and $  \theta \to 0 $ to $2\pi $
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi j} \int_0^{2\pi} cos (\theta) e^{j \theta}j \, d\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi } \int_0^{2\pi} cos (\theta) e^{j \theta} \, d\theta \quad \dots (5)$$
Now,
$$\int e^{ax}cos(bx) dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2 +b^2}\{ a cos(bx) + b sin (bx)\} +C \quad \dots  (6)$$
$$\implies \int_0^{2\pi} cos (\theta) e^{j \theta} \, d\theta = [\frac{e^{jx}}{j^2 +1^2}\{ j cos(x) +  sin (x)\}]_0^{2\pi}$$
Here, denominator is coming to $0$ , so we can't use the formula described in $eq(6)$;
Hence how to evaluate $eq(5)$ ?
Any help or suggestions please...

Comment: $Re\{ z\}$ isn't $r$, but $r\,\cos\theta$.

Comment: $Re\{r e^{i\theta}\} = r\cos(\theta)$ not $r$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; updated in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been noted, method 2 should be$$\frac{1}{2\pi j}\oint_cr\cos\theta d(re^{j\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}r^2\cos\theta e^{j\theta}d\theta=\frac{r^2}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2\theta d\theta=\frac12r^2=\frac12$$(although I'd rather insert $r=1$ at the start), as $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\theta\sin\theta d\theta=0$.

Comment: thanks a lot, it clear all my confusion

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{1 \over 2\pi\ic}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}
\Re\pars{z}\dd z} =
{1 \over 2\pi\ic}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}
{z + \overline{z} \over 2}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\pi\ic}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}
{1 \over 2}\pars{z + {1 \over z}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over 2}\,\pars{2\pi\ic \times 1} =
\bbx{1 \over 2} \\ & 
\end{align}

Comment: That's just repeating method 1. The question was how to repair method 2.